# What is the point of the US presidential code name?

Tags: united-states, president, national-security

What is the point of the US president having a code name?  I feel as if presidential (and other family/cabinet memebers) are widely reported and known. Is it that once they are accurately reported that the names must change? If not, why have them at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Service_code_name);

> The use of such names was originally for security purposes and dates to a time when sensitive electronic communications were not routinely encrypted; today, the names simply serve for purposes of brevity, clarity, and tradition.

As @o.m. pointed out in a comment, there can be more than one family member with the same name, as was true for the Bush family. American Presidents also continue to be referred to as Mr President or President *Last Name* for life as mentioned in this [Huffington Post](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/forms-of-address-how-to-a_b_2390778) snippet. So even just using the job title could cause confusion in certain circumstances.